# Content Width Won't Resize to 100%;

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

With the exception of the nav-bar, the content width of my pages won't resize to 100%. As you resize the browser window, the content will stretch to a certain width, and then stop.

I've set the width of all elements to 100% to no avail.

This only occurs when serving pages from my development machine, which is running IIS Express 8.0. It does not occur on the Test and Development servers, which are running IIS 8.5.

Comment: can you give us the code?

Answer (score 0):

Everything within the body of the page would max out at a width of around 1000px.

The only thing that has worked to fix this is simply setting the max width for body to 1900px.

I don't know where in Bootstrap the body is being limited to a smaller width.